# Potentiometer as input for MSP430g2452 launchpad

Tags: c, arrays, msp430

i'm new to the programming world, and i'm working on a project with light. 
It's nothing fancy, it's just to learn some basics. But i have 3 potentiometers, where the idea is to turn on/off a LED, 1 pot' for 1 LED.

i am using a MSP430g2452 launchpad, and would like to use: 
P1.1 - 1.2 - 1.3 for the pots 
&
P2.3 - 2.4 - 2.5 for the LEDs

because thats how a made the product to fit..

My teacher said i should use a code (link will be here somewhere), and just get to it... 
But i don't know shit, so it is a little hard do to "just do it" .. (The data from pots will be put in an array)

hope someone can help me, either with some links where i can read what to do, or simply explain what to do and why.. :P

**Q:

How can i get the potentiometers to work? I would like to know how i program them to work as on/off.. if the value is under this then that etc..**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3fjy5Ck2QKBOEo2bm4td3M3Z00/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So, what are you asking? Do you have anything you want to achieve?

Comment: How i can get the potentiometers to work?
I would like to know how i program them to work as on/off.. 
if the value is under this then that etc..

Comment: Did you noticed that the data sheet http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430g2452.pdf does not contain anything about potentiometers. But P1.2 can be an ADC input.

Comment: Did you compile and run the program your teacher gave you. What didn't work?

Comment: As said, i am completely new to this.. And my teacher just said, this is the template you are going to use. No explaining. So it's a bit frustrating..

Comment: and when I debug it and try to run it, it biulds the project, but it can open the file C:\Users\(my user)\workspace_v6_0\msp430g2x32_adc10_10\Debug\msp430g2x32_adc10_10.out

Comment: it can open? or can't open?

Comment: ups sorry... it can't open.. got to learn to read what i write..

Comment: This can't be answered here. Please ask your teacher and tell him that you can't connect the target. When you comeback please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get a sufficient answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to plug the middle terminal from the pots to the P1.1, 1.2, and 1.3 and assign these as inputs in the the code if this hasn't been done in the template. Attach the three LEDs to the pins you've indicated via one LED lead, and plug the other LED lead into GND, and assign these as LED outputs through the code. Use and IF or WHILE statement to program the LEDs to respond to the specific values output by the pots.